# Gnuplot - Reduce the space between graph and axis label

Tags: minipage, gnuplot

I'm using the minipage package to position two graphs, generated by gnuplot, side-by-side. I use the epslatex terminal. The graphs are rather small, and I'd like to increase their size by reducing the gap between each graph and its (vertical) y-axis label. How can I do this?

Comment: Reducing the space between the graph and the axis labels is something you'll have to do inside gnuplot: LaTeX can't really help you there.

Comment: I think you misunderstand: surely _only_ a gnuplot solution is possible. LaTeX can't modify your pictures on the fly the way you seem to want it to. And this isn't the right place to be asking for gnuplot solutions.

Comment: Move to superuser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnuplot's epslatex terminal generates an encapsulated postscript file containing the graph, and a tex file containing commands to import the graph and add labels, etc. The labels are added using the picture environment; just change the coordinates in the tex file if you want to move them.

Answer (score 14):

The `set ylabel` command can be given an optional x or y position offset. Beware though, for me, Gnuplot 4.4 gave errors relating to a missing semicolon. The older Gnuplot 4.2.4 worked fine. For example:

```
set ylabel "angels" 5
```

For Gnuplot 4.4, use the keyword "offset". For example:

```
set ylabel "angels" offset 2
```